# syntax for .max/.min and sum of hash values

Tags: ruby

Trying to get a value out of 2d array inside of a hash and determine its max or min value

This is what I have so far

```
pretend_hash = { 333 => [Dog,19.99], 222=> [Cat,25.55] }

if a == 5                    # Loop for view highest priced product"
 puts "View highest priced product"
 puts pretend_hash.values.max 
end
```

So this returns the highest alphabetical value in the first part of the array by default
Which would be Dog. How do I go about getting access to the 2nd part of the array where 25.55 gets declared the .max value? Something like pretend_hash.values.max[|k,v,z| print z]
or a reverse on something?

The other problem I'm having is iterating through 2nd hash elements and determining the sum. Again callling that 2nd element in the array is something I'm not able to find the syntax for.   I mean its not hard to say 19.99+25.55 = some variable and slam it into a puts. I'm assuming its something like:

```
pretend_hash.sum{|k,v,z| ?? } 

#I assume it iterates through the z element
#and adds all current z values and returns the sum?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Min/max can be solved like this:

```
pretend_hash.values.sort{|x,y| x[1] <=> y[1]}[0] # Gives min, -1 will be max
```

Or:

```
pretend_hash.values.map{|x| x[1]}.max
```

And sum can be had like this:

```
pretend_hash.values.inject(0){|sum,x| sum+x[1]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    pretend_hash = { 333 => ["Dog",19.99], 222=> ["Cat",25.55] }


    key,value = pretend_hash.max{|a,b| b[1] <=> a[1]}
    puts key.to_s
    puts value.join(',')


    puts pretend_hash.inject(0){|sum, hash| sum + hash[1][1]}.to_s

#returns:
#222
#Cat,25.55
#45.54
```